# When is it safe to call TIdTCPConnection.Disconnect?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

I have a `h: TIdHTTP` component in a secondary thread and it's retrieving headers from a URL. At the same time user clicks cancel and the main thread tries to actually disconnect the `Indy` component. Is it safe to call `thrd.h.Disconnect`  from the main thread? (while `h:TIdHTTP` is declared as public so is accessible within the main thread)

If it is safe at anytime, may I write a `Cancel` function in the thread that can be called directly by the main thread?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the main thread can call `Disconnect()` on the socket while the worker thread is busy reading/writing data over the same socket.  The read/write operation will raise an exception that the thread can catch or ignore as needed.

You could also assign an event handler to the `TIdHTTP.OnWork` event and have it raise an exception, such as with `SysUtils.Abort()`, if the thread is being terminated.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by 'safe' :)   The TidHTTP will raise an exception in the secondary thread when its socket is ripped out from underneath it.  If you catch that and handle it, (log it, display it or just ignore it), then you should be fine.

A 'cancel' method of the thread/socket/whatever object should be OK too - you can then keep the TidHTTP component as a private field.